# Is there a Python version of CPAN?

Tags: python

So I've been using Perl for several years now and I'm starting to dabble a little in Python. Is there a sort of CPAN but for Python? What's the normal way to manage modules in Python? Any direction would be greatly appreciated. FWIW I use Linux so Windows-only solutions aren't really useful to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The repository formerly known as Cheese Shop](http://pypi.python.org/pypi).

> ### [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi)
>
> The Python Package Index is a repository of software for the Python programming language. There are currently 9140 packages here. To contact the PyPI admins, please use the [Get help](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=66150&atid=513504) or [Bug reports](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=66150&atid=513503) links.

Also, take a look at

> ### [SIG for Python Resource Cataloguing](http://www.python.org/community/sigs/current/catalog-sig/)
>
> This SIG exists in order to discuss and build a catalog of Python resources. The SIG charter is:
>
> > The Python Catalog SIG (*Special Interest Group*) aims at producing a master index of Python software and other resources. It will begin by figuring out what the requirements are, converging on a design for the data schema, and producing an implementation. ("Implementation" will almost certainly include mean a set of CGI scripts for browsing the catalog, and may also contain a standard library module for automatically fetching and installing modules, if the SIG decides that's a worthwhile feature.)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Python eggs / easy_install](http://mrtopf.de/blog/python_zope/a-small-introduction-to-python-eggs/)